# Next UIView is not being shown when row is selected

Tags: iphone

my next View is not displayed & in that i use imageview & scrollview. My code look like this

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VolunteerPhotoDetail *volunteerPhotoDetail = [[VolunteerPhotoDetail alloc]initWithNibName:@"VolunteerPhotoDetail" bundle:nil];
    volunteerPhotoDetail.indexRow = indexPath.row;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:volunteerPhotoDetail animated:YES];
    NSLog(@" self.navigationController  0x%x", self.navigationController);
    [volunteerPhotoDetail release];
}
```

nslog display value of the selg.navigationController but view is not displayed
I check all the IB conncetion properly so please give me answer

Comment: Can you post some code of the VolunteerPhotoDetail class?

Comment: Lee.. your question heading is really poor.. Please make good heading

Comment: ??? Not my question, I was replying.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be because you set your bundle to nil. 
Replace nil by `[NSBundle mainBundle]`